# Single Sample vs Population Non-normally distributed

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions

I have rna-seq gene expression data (but could also be reads assigned to species) where most of the genes are expressed at low levels, and the units are discrete ranging from 0 to the total number of reads for the sample. Some genes are only expressed in the case.

I have a population of controls (n=30) and a single case (n=1). I am looking to find the probability that the expression within the case of each gene does not fall within the distribution of the controls, similar to a standard score.

Example:

[image]

1. Is the negative binomial distribution appropriate?
2. Is there an equivalent to the z-score that I could use to calculate a significance value of deviation from the control distribution?

I tried something similar in DESeq2 and it was able to produce a p-value; however I am uncertain whether it assumes the same distribution for cases and controls.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you tring to compare? Mean, variance, distribution?

Comment: The single sample vs the distribution of controls - kind of like z-score the case, but for a negative binomial distribution if appropriate, and then convert to p-value.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a negative binomial test? It exists. I don't know what software you are using, but in R for ex. you have exact.nb.test, which returns a statistic and p-value, just like a z-test.